# insert into new table from existing table with an added new field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert (a monthly backup I'll be restoring into my source_database) into the dest_database, and add a new DATE field which would state which month is the data from. So in the end everything will be in the dest_database with the DATE field specifying to which month it belongs.

What'd I need to do?

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
(SELECT *
FROM source_table)
```

Comment: use month(getdate()) for getting the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the column names and add the extra column.

See the **new_date_col1** in the below sql.

```
INSERT INTO dest_table ( old_col1, old_col2, new_date_col1) 
SELECT old_col1, old_col2, getdate() FROM source_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created the dest_table with the same fields and datatype as the source_table, you would just need to add a single column to that table prior to the insert.

```
create table dest_table 
(column1 <datatype>,
...,
...,
LoadDate datetime);
GO

insert into dest_table (column1,...,LoadDate)
select 
   column1, 
   ..., 
   getdate() 
from source_table
```

Or, simply

```
select 
   column1, 
   ..., 
   getdate() 
into dest_table 
from source_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as shown below

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3, DATE_Field)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, GETDATE() 
FROM oldTable
```

Comment: While the OP did state they wanted the month it belongs to, I'd caution against this since if the data spans multiple years you wouldn't know which year the month belonged to.

Answer (score 0):

If the table definition of `source_table` and `dest_table` are the same except for the extra `TimeStamp` column, you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table 
SELECT *,MONTH(GETDATE()) 
FROM source_table
```

Otherwise, you need to specify the mapping relation, for example:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table (col1,col2...,Date_Column) 
SELECT col3,col4...,MONTH(GETDATE()) 
FROM source_table
```

Comment: While the OP did state they wanted the month it belongs to, I'd caution against this since if the data spans multiple years you wouldn't know which year the month belonged to.

Comment: you're right, but not sure what the real scenario is xD